# Verwendung von "es" bei Infinitivsätzen

Tags: infinitive

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen

> Das Ziel dieses Projektes ist, die Einflussfaktoren auf die Qualitätschwankungen zu bestimmen.

und

> Das Ziel dieses Projektes ist **es**, die Einflussfaktoren auf die Qualitätschwankungen zu bestimmen.

Ein anderes Beispiel:

> Hier ist ersichtlich, dass die Qualität ein wichtiges Merkmal darstellt.

und

> Hier ist **es** ersichtlich, dass die Qualität ein wichtiges Merkmal darstellt.

Comment: Wo ist der _Infinitiv_ in dem 2. Beispielsatz?

Answer (score 3):

Der Unterschied ist m.E. die *Emphase*.

> > Das Ziel dieses Projektes ist **es**, die Einflussfaktoren auf die Qualitätschwankungen zu bestimmen.

Es betont *Das Ziel*.

> > Hier ist **es** ersichtlich, dass die Qualität ein wichtiges Merkmal darstellt.

Es betont *ersichtlich* (*es ist ersichtlich*).

---

Grammatikalisch gesehen sind alle genannten Formen korrekt, und es gäbe weitere, wie z.B.:

> Ziel des Projektes ist, die Einflussfaktoren auf die Qualitätschwankungen zu bestimmen.
>
> Ziel des Projektes ist es , die Einflussfaktoren auf die Qualitätschwankungen zu bestimmen.
>
> Es ist ersichtlich, dass die Qualität ein wichtiges Merkmal darstellt.

Comment: Ein anderer Grund, *es* zu verwenden (oder auch nicht) könnte der Rhythmus des Satzes sein. Manchmal klingt es besser mit, manchmal ohne. Entscheidend dafür ist (es), den Satz im Kontext zu sehen.

Comment: @Christian Is Rhythmus nicht irgendwie kohärent mit _Emphase_ (sprich Betonung)?

Comment: Ich finde nicht; jedenfalls nicht unbedingt. Ich kann das "es" benützen, ohne den Satzteil inhaltlich betonen zu wollen, sondern nur weil es mir rhythmisch besser in den Kram passt. Ein Beispiel in Versen: *So mag man es denn wohl entscheiden / das "es" wenn möglich zu vermeiden.* Hier ist das "es" nur wegen des Rhythmus drin. (Das geht auch in Prosa, natürlich, aber in Versen zeigt es sich leichter.)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Mir scheint es, dass "wenn möglich" ein wenig holpert, da bin ich wohl über fehlende Kommata gestolpert. (SCNR)